# Is possible inflate more layouts?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to inflate layout according next conditions:

```
if (...) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_menu_item, null);
}
else {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_menu_index, null);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_menu_item, null);
}
```

Layout `customer_menu_index` is for insertion of index letter to the menu list. Second layout inserts basic menu item.

How can I inflate two different layouts in one calling of method `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)` included in `BaseAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know whether this will solve your purpose, but can't you implement a xml file containing both the layouts. And then you can just manipulate their visibility like,

view = inflater.inflate("the_layout_from_your_xml", null);

if (...){

```
   view.finViewByID(R.id.customer_menu_index).setVisibility(false);
```

} else{

```
   view.finViewByID(R.id.customer_menu_index).setVisibility(true);
```

}

Does that work for you?

Comment: thanks, your advice resolved this problem. The solution with two separated XML layouts is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I inflate two different layouts in one calling of method `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)` included in `BaseAdapter`.

There is no limitation on how many times you can call `inflate()`, aside from the device's memory. However your else block immediately overwrites the first value of `view` so consider using a different variable.

If you plan on using multiple row layouts, you must override the `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods or you will see erratic behaviour while scrolling your ListView, Spinner, etc.

Comment: you're right, there is no limitation. But second calling overwrites me the first value. Returned value of `getView` is inflated View, so I should inflate views to the same variable.